# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) some issue in my front end back end works

Tags: reactjs, express, fetch-api, mern

This is my form

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const ItemForm = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('')
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('')
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('')
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const [date, setDate] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const item = {name, category, price, quantity, description, date};
    
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/add-item', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    const json = await response.json()

    if (!response.ok) {
      setError(json.error)
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      setError(null)
      setName('')
      setCategory('')
      setPrice('')
      setQuantity('')
      setDescription('')
      setDate('')
      console.log('new item added:', json)
    }

  }

  return (
    <form className="create" onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
      <h3>Add a New Item</h3>

      <label>Item Name:</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} 
        value={name}
      />

      <label>Category:</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)} 
        value={category}
      />

      <label>Price:</label>
      <input 
        type="number" 
        onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} 
        value={price} 
      />

     <label>Quantity:</label>
      <input 
        type="number" 
        onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)} 
        value={quantity} 
      />

     <label>Description:</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} 
        value={description} 
      />

     <label>Date:</label>
      <input 
        type="date" 
        onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)} 
        value={date} 
      />

      <button>Add Workout</button>
      {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
    </form>
  )
}

export default ItemForm;
```

here is my routing:

```
const { addItem, getItems,getItem,deleteItem,updateItem} = require('../controllers/itemController');


const router = require('express').Router();



router.post('/add-item', addItem)
      .get('/get-items', getItems)
      .get('/get-item/:id', getItem)
      .delete('/delete-item/:id', deleteItem)
      .patch('/update-item/:id', updateItem)
module.exports = router
```

my controller:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const ItemSchema = require("../models/itemModel")


exports.addItem = async (req, res) => {
    //destructuring request body into its components
    const {name, category, price, quantity, description, date} = req.body

    //storing all of these values from the request body into the item variable
    const item = ItemSchema({
        name,
        category,
        price,
        quantity,
        description,
        date
    })

    //validations 
    try {
        if(!name || !category || !price || !quantity|| !description || !date){
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'All fields are required!'})
        }
        
        if(price <= 0 || typeof price !== 'number'){
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'Valid price required'})
        }
        //saving data into the database
        await item.save()
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Item was added'})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: 'Server Error'})
    }
    
}

exports.getItems = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //finding all items, showing the last items entered first
        const items = await ItemSchema.find().sort({createdAt: -1})
        res.status(200).json(items)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message:'Server Error'})
    }

}

exports.deleteItem = async (req, res) => {
    //storing object id from the req parameters
    const {id} = req.params;

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        return res.status(404).json({error: 'no such item'})
    }
    
    const item = await ItemSchema.findByIdAndDelete({_id:id})

    if(!item){
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'No such item'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(item)
    
}

exports.getItem = async (req, res) => {
    //storing object id from the req parameters
    const {id} = req.params;
    //finding and deleting said item from database
    const item= await ItemSchema.findById(id)

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        return res.status(404).json({error: 'no such item'})
    }

    if(!item){
        return res.status(404).json({error: 'No such item'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(item)
}

exports.updateItem = async (req, res) => {
    //storing object id from the req parameters
    const {id} = req.params;

    if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        return res.status(404).json({error: 'no such item'})
    }
    
    const item = await ItemSchema.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id},{
        ...req.body
    })

    if(!item){
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'No such item'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(item)
    
}
```

my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            maxLength: 30
        },
        category: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            maxLength: 30
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            min: 0,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
            maxLength: 50,   
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
            trim: true
        }
        

},{timestamps: true})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema)
```

this is what the console replies:

> in.8993af04c71d3db87ea2.hot-update.js:43     POST  http://localhost:5000/api/v1/add-item 400 (Bad Request)
> handle.

I think some this is wrong with the form since the back end works fine and I already tested it. I'm new to mern stack and I am unable to find the reason why I get this issue. Please help.

I wanted to make the form to add a new item and display it in the home page. I tried using the fetch API and converted it into JSON and it still doesn't work.